# Begin date of application in android that never changes

Tags: android, datetime

I am working on app in which i want to use begins date when user stared using that app.that date never changes.i have gone through http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html bt didnt find any method

Comment: Get the current date and save it in userDefaults, if it hasn't been saved before.

Comment: can you please guide me how to strore it in user defaults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current date:

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String date = formatter.format(date);
```

Then you want to store this value using SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
      "MYAPP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putString("DATE", date).commit();
```

if you want to retrieve that value:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
      "MYAPP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String myDate = prefs.getString("DATE", "string to return if null");
```

Learn More: [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) and [SharedPreferences Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)